# Can I calculate the integral of the O ring statistic from Ripley's K function?

Tags: r, spatial

I need to calculate the integral of the O ring statistic, and I do not see any available package to use in Rstudio that can provide me with this value.

For example, here is the O ring statistic plot for a given landscape.

[image]

To calculate this I first generate a landscape, and then use spatialEco package to generate the graph. I also include the Ripley's K plot below.

```
library('spatstat')
library('ggplot2')
library('spatialEco')

set.seed(seed=24)

radiusCluster<-100
lambdaParent<-.02
lambdaDaughter<-30
hosts<-1000
randmod<-0
dim<-2000


numbparents<-rpois(1,lambdaParent*dim)

xxParent<-runif(numbparents,0+radiusCluster,dim-radiusCluster)
yyParent<-runif(numbparents,0+radiusCluster,dim-radiusCluster)

numbdaughter<-rpois(numbparents,(lambdaDaughter))
sumdaughter<-sum(numbdaughter)



thetaLandscape<-2*pi*runif(sumdaughter)

rho<-radiusCluster*sqrt(runif(sumdaughter))


xx0=rho*cos(thetaLandscape)
yy0=rho*sin(thetaLandscape)


xx<-rep(xxParent,numbdaughter)
yy<-rep(yyParent,numbdaughter)

xx<-xx+xx0

yy<-yy+yy0
cds<-data.frame(xx,yy)
is_outlier<-function(x){
  x > dim| x < 0
}
cds<-cds[!(is_outlier(cds$xx)|is_outlier(cds$yy)),]
while (nrow(cds)<hosts){
 dif<-hosts-nrow(cds)
  extraparentxx<-sample(xxParent,dif,replace = TRUE)
  extraparentyy<-sample(yyParent,dif,replace = TRUE)
  extrathetaLandscape<-2*pi*runif(dif)
  extrarho<-radiusCluster*sqrt(runif(dif))
  newextracoodsxx<-extrarho*cos(extrathetaLandscape)
  newextracoodsyy<-extrarho*sin(extrathetaLandscape)
  extraxx<-extraparentxx+newextracoodsxx
  extrayy<-extraparentyy+newextracoodsyy
  cdsextra<-data.frame(xx=extraxx,yy=extrayy)
  cds<-rbind(cds,cdsextra)
}


sampleselect<-sample(1:nrow(cds),hosts,replace=F)
cds<-cds%>%slice(sampleselect)

randfunction<-function(x){
  x<-runif(length(x),0,dim)
}
randselect<-sample(1:nrow(cds),floor(hosts*randmod),replace=F)
cds[randselect,]<-apply(cds[randselect,],1,randfunction)

landscape<-ppp(x=cds$xx,y=cds$yy,window=owin(xrange=c(0,dim),yrange=c(0,dim)))
ggplot(data.frame(landscape))+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+coord_equal()+theme_minimal()

ostat<-o.ring(landscape,inhomogenous=FALSE)

plot1<-Kest(landscape)
plot(plot1)
```

I do not know of a method in which I can calculate the area under this curve (this was made using the "spatialEco" package).

However, I understand that the O ring statistic is $\frac{dK(r)}{dr}\frac{1}{2 \pi r}\lambda$ With r representing distance from a point, lambda being the intensity of the pattern and K representing the Ripley's K function.

My background is not in mathematics, so my mathematics is probably wrong, but the integral of the O ring statistic would be $K(r)\frac{ln(r)}{2\pi}\lambda r$

So for example, using a different package, spatstat, I can calculate the Ripley's K function for the same landscape.

[image]

I assume that the Ripley's K function part of the above equation is the difference between the edge corrected Ripley's K (such as the Isotropic line). In spatstat, it is possible to isolate the values given in the Ripley's K plot. So for example, if we use the value of Ripley's K iso at r =500, which is 968128.9, and the theoretical distribution which is 785398.2, then their difference is 182730.2.

So the integral of the O-ring statistic between 0 and 500 would be:

$182730.2 \frac{ln(500)}{2\pi}500\lambda$

I do not know how to calculate the intensity of the pattern, but is this a correct assumption? If not, what is the correct assumption and would you know how to calculate the integral of the O-ring statistic?

Many thanks for taking the time to read my question, and even more so if you have any suggestions. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intensity of a point can be estimated by the number of points divided by the area of the window (survey region). In spatstat you estimate it by `intensity(X)` where `X` is the point pattern. It is not clear to me why you need the integral of the so-called O-ring statistic which is not standard in my field. We mention the statistic and its close connection to the pair correlation function in Chapter 7 of the spatstat book. You can download Chapter 7 as a free sample from the book website http://book.spatstat.org/ and I really think you could benefit from looking through this. Good luck!